# creating a path to wordpress in SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, path, ssh-tunnel, wp-cli

I made a rookie mistake that I'm trying to correct.

I need to access a wordpress installation and edit the database, but the host doesn't provide a control panel or phpMyadmin so I set up an ssh tunnel. I installed wp cli and verified the installation. It all looks right

```
    $ php wp-cli.phar --info
    OS:     Linux 4.15.0-147-generic #151-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 18 19:21:19         
    UTC 2021 x86_64
    Shell:  /bin/bash
    PHP binary:     /RunCloud/Packages/php74rc/bin/php
    PHP version:    7.4.21
    php.ini used:   /etc/php74rc/php.ini
    MySQL binary:   /usr/bin/mysql
    MySQL version:  mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.40-MariaDB, for debian- 
    linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
    SQL modes:
    WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
    WP-CLI vendor dir:      phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
    WP_CLI phar path:       /home/wordpress_installation (assumed)
    WP-CLI packages dir:
    WP-CLI global config:
    WP-CLI project config:
    WP-CLI version: 2.5.0`
```

But when I used a wp command, I got an error `this doesn't appear to be a wordpress installation` I was pretty sure I had the right path, and the error said to `download wordpress`. So I did that. But now it's asking for me to make a config file

```
'wp-config.php' not found. Either create one manually or use `wp config create`
```

I don't want to do that. I must have the wrong path and will need to get that information from the host. But in the meantime, How can undo the wordpress installation.
Or get back to

```
    WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
    WP-CLI vendor dir:      phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
    WP_CLI phar path:       /home/wordpress_installation (assumed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got bold/reckless and tried a few things. I was able to find find the directories and get the correct one. So now I have a WordPress download on the server but I'm not tied to it. I could probably just go onto the FTP and delete the files. But I'm chicken.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.